# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el footer no se coma mi contenido?

Tags: html, css

estoy tratando de hacer que el footer se quede abajo, pero por más que intento se come el contenido de los div, ¿qué puedo hacer?
Aquí el code:

```
 footer {
            
            position: fixed !important;
            bottom: 0 !important;
            clear: both !important;
        }
```

Adjunto captura[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Elimina el fixed y coloca relative;

Comment: Genial @AndresLinares gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución:
Reemplazamos en el code `position:fixed;` por `position:relative;`

Comment: @Israel-ICM soy el mismo que ha hecho la pregunta, añado esa parte que fue  con la que Andrés me ayudó

Comment: Saludos @galaxiaGalicia, el comentario que viste es autogenerado cuando se marca una pregunta como comentario, lo que sucede es que para que una respuesta sea mejor recibida es mucho mejor si agregas un poco mas de explicación y links de documentación, de esta forma ayudaras a otros usuarios iniciantes a comprender tu solución, de esta forma también ganaras más puntos de reputación, si solo agregas el cómo y no el porqué solo parece un comentario y no así una respuesta. ;)